# How to reset AnimatedSprite?

Tags: animation, godot

In Godot v2, it seems that `AnimatedSprite` had a method `set_frame()` see [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/2.1/classes/class_animatedsprite.html).

But in v3, this method does not seem to exist anymore. Only 3 methods are available see [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/fr/stable/classes/class_animatedsprite.html):

```
bool is_playing ()

void play (String anim="", bool backwards=false )

void stop ()
```

What is the way to reset an animation in Godot 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the [`frame`](https://docs.godotengine.org/fr/stable/classes/class_animatedsprite.html#class-animatedsprite-property-frame) property of the `AnimatedSprite`.

Comment: Shame on me! After the accessors discussion we had on SO....